# Beautifulsoup - findAll not finding string when link is also in container

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using the findAll function in beautifulsoup to scrape a webpage for text and return the results in a list. For some reason it doesn't return entries when there is also a link in the `td` container. For example:

```
<html   
<tr>
 <td>
  Taken at. string without link, this is found
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  Taken at. string followed by link, this is not found
  <a href="http://www.thisisalink.com/index.html">
   text for link
  </a>
 </td>
</tr>
</html>
```

The first `td` container is returned but the second also containing a link is not with the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

genus = 'Parsonsia'
species = 'straminea'

page = requests.get("https://www.anbg.gov.au/cgi-bin/apiiName?030=" + genus + "+" + species)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

grep_str = '^Taken at.*$'
pattern = re.compile(grep_str)
location = soup.findAll('td', text=pattern)

for item in location:
    print(item)
```

How do I get the findAll function to return both instances? The result is being placed in a data.frame with other scraped data so it's important to find all these instances at once in the correct order.

Cheers!

Comment: it won't return anything with current code, not even The first `td` container

Comment: Apologies, my example must have broken the code. Let me edit the question.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks for pointing out the code wasn't working. Should work now.

Comment: that's really strange, it doesn't extract them ... perhaps, soup bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, I've tested the case and it seems that `BeautifulSoup` does not give the expected result. 
Use [**`lxml.html`**](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) library instead:

```
import lxml.html as html
import requests

genus = 'Parsonsia'
species = 'straminea'

page = requests.get("https://www.anbg.gov.au/cgi-bin/apiiName?030=" + genus + "+" + species)
root = html.fromstring(page.content)
for td in root.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Taken at')]"):
    print(td.text_content())
```

The actual output:

```
Taken at. ANBG nursery
Taken at. ANBG
Taken at. ANBG
Taken at. Robertson to Belmore Falls Road, NSW
Taken at. Robertson to Belmore Falls Road, NSW
Taken at. Robertson to Belmore Falls Road, NSW
Taken at. Robertson to Belmore Falls Road, NSW
Taken at. Back Hillston Rd, near Goolgowi, NSW
Taken at. shoreline, Tuross Head, NSW
Taken at. shoreline, Tuross Head, NSW
Taken at. shoreline, Tuross Head, NSW
Taken at. shoreline, Tuross Head, NSW
Taken at. shoreline, Tuross Head, NSW
Taken at. Tuross Head, near Memorial Gardens, Tuross, NSW
Taken at. Tuross Head, near Memorial Gardens, Tuross, NSW
Taken at. Lake Conjola beach, N of Ulladulla, NSW
Taken at. Chain Valley Bay, Lake Macquarie State Conservation Area, NSW
Taken at. Chain Valley Bay, Lake Macquarie State Conservation Area, NSW
Taken at. Wright's Lookout walk, New England Nat Pk,  NSW
Taken at. Wright's Lookout walk, New England Nat Pk,  NSW
Taken at. Wright's Lookout walk, New England Nat Pk, NSW
Taken at. Boondall Wet Lands, Brisbane  QLD
Taken at. Boondall Wet Lands, Brisbane  QLD
Taken at. Boondall Wet Lands, Brisbane  QLD
Taken at. see Australian Tropical Rainforest Plants Key
Taken at. see Australian Tropical Rainforest Plants Key
Taken at. see Australian Tropical Rainforest Plants Key
Taken at. see Australian Tropical Rainforest Plants Key
Taken at. see Australian Tropical Rainforest Plants Key
Taken at. see Australian Tropical Rainforest Plants Key
```

http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html

Comment: Thanks Roman. I'll have to familiarise myself with that package.

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting. I don't know why it happens, but here's a workaround.

You can first pull all the `td` tags into a list and then filter it based on the text they contain.

```
td_all = soup.findAll('td')
location = list(filter(lambda td: 'Taken at.' in td.text, td_all))
```

If you're going to iterate through the `location` just once in your code, it's better to remove the `list` conversion, and use the `filter` object directly in your loop:

```
location = filter(lambda td: 'Taken at.' in td.text, td_all)
```

**Edit: *Alternative Solution***

The page you're trying to scrape is structured enough. So it's easy to navigate through it (at least for the page you've mentioned in your question).

Since each image index is contained within a `tr`, we can pull all of those into a list first. But since there are nested tables within each of these `tr` elements, we'll have to fetch only the direct children, which can be accomplished using `recursive=False` argument of the `findAll` method.

```
trows = soup.table.tbody.findAll('tr', recursive=False)

for trow in trows[1:]:
    print(trow.findAll('tr')[1].td.text)
```

I've iterated only from the 2nd item in the list since the first one is the header row.

This gives prints out the entire list of 30 plants:

```
Taken at. ANBG nursery
Taken at. ANBG
Taken at. ANBG
Taken at. Robertson to Belmore Falls Road, NSW
Taken at. Robertson to Belmore Falls Road, NSW
Taken at. Robertson to Belmore Falls Road, NSW
Taken at. Robertson to Belmore Falls Road, NSW
Taken at. Back Hillston Rd, near Goolgowi, NSW
Taken at. shoreline, Tuross Head, NSW
Taken at. shoreline, Tuross Head, NSW
Taken at. shoreline, Tuross Head, NSW
Taken at. shoreline, Tuross Head, NSW
Taken at. shoreline, Tuross Head, NSW
Taken at. Tuross Head, near Memorial Gardens, Tuross, NSW
Taken at. Tuross Head, near Memorial Gardens, Tuross, NSW
Taken at. Lake Conjola beach, N of Ulladulla, NSW
Taken at. Chain Valley Bay, Lake Macquarie State Conservation Area, NSW
Taken at. Chain Valley Bay, Lake Macquarie State Conservation Area, NSW
Taken at. Wright's Lookout walk, New England Nat Pk,  NSW
Taken at. Wright's Lookout walk, New England Nat Pk,  NSW
Taken at. Wright's Lookout walk, New England Nat Pk, NSW
Taken at. Boondall Wet Lands, Brisbane  QLD
Taken at. Boondall Wet Lands, Brisbane  QLD
Taken at. Boondall Wet Lands, Brisbane  QLD
Taken at. see Australian Tropical Rainforest Plants Key
Taken at. see Australian Tropical Rainforest Plants Key
Taken at. see Australian Tropical Rainforest Plants Key
Taken at. see Australian Tropical Rainforest Plants Key
Taken at. see Australian Tropical Rainforest Plants Key
Taken at. see Australian Tropical Rainforest Plants Key
```